# Optimize tempdb log files

Tags: optimization, sql-server-2008-r2, tempdb

Have a dedicated DB server with 16 cores and 200+ GB of memory.

Use tempdb a lot but it typically stays under 4 GB

Recently added a dedicated SSD stripe for tempdb

Based on this page should create multiple files

[Optimizing tempdb Performance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175527%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Understand multiple row files.

Here is my question:
Should I also create multiple tempdb log files?

It does say "create one data file for each CPU".
So my thought is that data means row (not log) files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, as with all databases, SQL server can only use one log file at a time so there is no benefit at all in having multiple log files.

The best thing you can do with log files really is keep them on separate drives to the data files as they have different IO requirements, pre-size them so they don't have to auto grow and if they do have to autogrow, make sure they do so at a sensible level to manage the number of virtual log files that are created inside them.

Comment: I believe you but what is strange is SSMS will let me create addition log files.

Comment: Yep, it will let you, but you really shouldn't do it, have a look at this article by Paul Randall for an explanation http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/multiple-log-files-and-why-theyre-bad/

Comment: Sorry to keep this going but if I only had one SSD stripe would it still be better to have a separate log?  I have 4 SSD in the stripe.  Could put 3 in the stripe and one for the log.   My thought is a bigger stripe and let it manage the load.

Comment: I can't really answer that as I don't know your IO requirements, once you know these it will be clearer where you need to put these files, whether a shared drive for tempdb log and data is ok or not. What I wouldn't suggest is using a single drive for the tempdb log as if that one drive fails, your whole server goes down.

Comment: But right now tempdp is on a stripe so if one drive goes down so does the db.

Comment: You're not talking RAID 0 right? On a production system? Please say no. Get that changed, it's a terrible setup.

Comment: Yes it is RAID 0.   It is tempdb so what if it fails.  I want speed.

Comment: You know if tempDB fails that your SQL server goes offline right?